# How can I activate the new Facebook design?

Tags: facebook

I really like the (IMHO long overdue) [redesign of Facebook](https://www.ghacks.net/2020/02/11/this-is-how-facebooks-new-desktop-design-looks-and-how-you-can-restore-the-old-facebook/). I saw in a video, that you can manually activate it in the top right menu just below the "Settings":

[image]

However, I don't see this option in my menu. Is there any way to still activate it?

[image]